# Why can't OCMod find lines of code?

Tags: opencart, ocmod

I have an issue with OCMod, it randomly seems to not find lines of code, see below:

```
<file path="catalog/language/english/product/ymmproduct.php">
        <operation>
            <search trim="true"><![CDATA[
              $_['tab_vehicle']    = 'Vehicles';
              ]]></search>
            <add position="replace"><![CDATA[
              $_['tab_vehicle']    = 'Bikes';
              ]]></add>
        </operation>
    </file>
```

- the file path and ned is correct
- i've tried the search with and without trimming [I'm guessing at what 'trim' does because it's not documented]
- the line of code I'm searching for is absolutely there - I cut and pasted it from the target file then diff'd the contents.... NO DIFFERENCE.
- I've tried it with and without line feeds in the CDATA

Nothing I have tried will find that line of code.

What could the issue be?

Comment: What is the version of your opencart?

Answer (score 0):

OCMod is not robust for a multiline search.  If you can figure out how to do a single line search, it will be much more likely to work consistently.  Since the file `catalog/language/english/product/ymmproduct.php` isn't in the default installation, is it yours?  Perhaps you can create lines in it that will help guide OCMod so a single line search will work properly.